# question about basis and norm( conception and computation)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image: question]

This is a multiple-choice question. I think the first choice is correct, because the x is the coefficient and $\phi_i$ is the basis. And I think the third is false because $\parallel\phi_i\parallel_2 = \sqrt{P}$ (intuition)

But how is the second and fourth? And is my solution correct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is incorrect as $\{\phi_i\}$ is an orthogonal basis, but not necessarily an *orthonormal* basis. What we actually have is that for all $x \in \Bbb R^N$ (try to prove it):

$$x = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac1{\|\phi_i\|^2} \langle x , \phi_i \rangle \phi_i$$

So,

$$\|x\|^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac1{\|\phi_i \|^2} \langle x , \phi_i \rangle ^2  \tag1 $$

Now, you can see that the sufficient conditions in $2$ and $4$ are correct. The necessary conditions are also correct (hint: $(1)$ holds for all $x\in \Bbb R^N$)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your first formula, the $x$ in the left side is vector or scalar? Is the $\phi_i$ in the right side vector?

Comment: @standerQiu you're welcome. It's a vector (before writing the formula I wrote: "for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$")

Comment: Oh! I know what you mean! Thanks for your answer!